# Scale BufferGeometry objects from their center

Tags: three.js, shader, glsles, buffer-geometry

I have a large number of randomly placed circles held in a single Buffer Geometry.  I'm trying to scale each one based on audio input from their centers, but they keep scaling w.r.t the center of the scene.  Instead of getting larger radii and staying still they get larger but also move further away from the center.

```
uniform float scale;
varying vec3 color;
void main() 
{

  mat4 sPos = mat4(vec4(scale,0.0,0.0,0.0),
               vec4(0.0,scale,0.0,0.0),
               vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0),
               vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0));
  vec3 pos = position * normal;
  vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * sPos * vec4(pos, 1.0) ;

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition;
}
```

This is what I'm trying.  Is there a matrix transform that can move the origin to the center of each circle without messing up other aspects of the scene?

[image: small scale value]
small scale value

[image: larger scale value]
larger scale value

Comment: (_Since you have `three.js` tagged, this is comment is from a purely three.js perspective._) Are you using a single buffer because multiple meshes degrades the performance? Have you considered using instances ([`InstancedBufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/InstancedBufferGeometry)) instead?

Comment: Yeah, the frame rate was dropping using circlebuffergeometry pretty quickly (~100-250 meshes).  I haven't considered using it, but I'm also unfamiliar with it.  Does it sound reasonable to have ~3000 - 5000 instances and maintain 60fps?

Comment: Follow-up question to your `circleBufferGeometry` comment: Were you re-using the geometry object, or were you creating a new `circleBufferGeometry` per mesh? I can't speculate on what kind of performance gains you'll see by using instances. You'll lose the efficiency of a single draw call (one mesh), but gain the ease-of-use of having multiple meshes.

Answer (score 2):

Add the normal * scale

```
uniform float scale;
varying vec3 color;
void main() 
{
  vec3 pos = position + normal * scale;
  vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0) ;

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition;
}
```

Example:

```js
const vs = `
uniform float scale;
void main() 
{
  vec3 pos = position + normal * scale;
  vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0) ;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition;
}
`;

const fs = `
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
`;

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, 1, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const uniforms = {
  scale: { value: 1 },
};

var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms:       uniforms,
  vertexShader:   vs,
  fragmentShader: fs,
});

const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
const numCircles = 20;
const numEdgePointsPerCircle = 36;
const numPointsPerCircle = numEdgePointsPerCircle * 3;
const totalPoints = numPointsPerCircle * numCircles;
const positions = new Float32Array(totalPoints * 3);
const normals = new Float32Array(totalPoints * 3);

const radius = 10;
let off = 0;

for (let c = 0; c < numCircles; ++c) {
  const cx = rand(-100, 100);
  const cy = rand(-100, 100);
  for (let p = 0; p < numEdgePointsPerCircle; ++p) {
    const a0 = (p + 0) * Math.PI * 2 / numEdgePointsPerCircle;
    const a1 = (p + 1) * Math.PI * 2 / numEdgePointsPerCircle;
    positions[off + 0] = cx;
    positions[off + 1] = cy;
    positions[off + 2] = 0;
    positions[off + 3] = cx + Math.cos(a0) * radius;
    positions[off + 4] = cy + Math.sin(a0) * radius;
    positions[off + 5] = 0;
    positions[off + 6] = cx + Math.cos(a1) * radius;
    positions[off + 7] = cy + Math.sin(a1) * radius;
    positions[off + 8] = 0;
    normals[off + 0] = 0;        
    normals[off + 1] = 0;        
    normals[off + 2] = 0;
    normals[off + 3] = Math.cos(a0);        
    normals[off + 4] = Math.sin(a0);        
    normals[off + 5] = 0;
    normals[off + 6] = Math.cos(a1);        
    normals[off + 7] = Math.sin(a1);        
    normals[off + 8] = 0;
    off += 9;
  }
}
 
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
geometry.addAttribute('normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute(normals, 3));

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, shaderMaterial );

scene.add(mesh);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: document.querySelector("canvas"),
});

function rand(min, max) {
  return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
}

function resize(renderer, camera, force) {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (force || canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);  // pass false so three doesn't mess up the css
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds
  
  resize(renderer, camera);
  
  uniforms.scale.value = Math.sin(time) * 5;
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
resize(renderer, camera, true);
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/86/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Example using just center point

```js
const vs = `
uniform float scale;
void main() 
{
  vec3 pos = position + normal * scale;
  vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0) ;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition;
}
`;

const fs = `
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
`;

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, 1, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const uniforms = {
  scale: { value: 1 },
};

var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms:       uniforms,
  vertexShader:   vs,
  fragmentShader: fs,
});

const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
const numCircles = 20;
const numEdgePointsPerCircle = 36;
const numPointsPerCircle = numEdgePointsPerCircle * 3;
const totalPoints = numPointsPerCircle * numCircles;
const positions = new Float32Array(totalPoints * 3);
const normals = new Float32Array(totalPoints * 3);

const radius = 10;
let off = 0;

for (let c = 0; c < numCircles; ++c) {
  const cx = rand(-100, 100);
  const cy = rand(-100, 100);
  for (let p = 0; p < numEdgePointsPerCircle; ++p) {
    const a0 = (p + 0) * Math.PI * 2 / numEdgePointsPerCircle;
    const a1 = (p + 1) * Math.PI * 2 / numEdgePointsPerCircle;
    positions[off + 0] = cx;
    positions[off + 1] = cy;
    positions[off + 2] = 0;
    positions[off + 3] = cx;
    positions[off + 4] = cy;
    positions[off + 5] = 0;
    positions[off + 6] = cx;
    positions[off + 7] = cy;
    positions[off + 8] = 0;
    normals[off + 0] = 0;        
    normals[off + 1] = 0;        
    normals[off + 2] = 0;
    normals[off + 3] = Math.cos(a0);        
    normals[off + 4] = Math.sin(a0);        
    normals[off + 5] = 0;
    normals[off + 6] = Math.cos(a1);        
    normals[off + 7] = Math.sin(a1);        
    normals[off + 8] = 0;
    off += 9;
  }
}
 
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
geometry.addAttribute('normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute(normals, 3));

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, shaderMaterial );

scene.add(mesh);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: document.querySelector("canvas"),
});

function rand(min, max) {
  return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
}

function resize(renderer, camera, force) {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (force || canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);  // pass false so three doesn't mess up the css
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds
  
  resize(renderer, camera);
  
  uniforms.scale.value = 10 + Math.sin(time) * 5;
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
resize(renderer, camera, true);
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/86/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Example using instancing

```js
const vs = `
attribute vec3 center;
uniform float scale;
void main() 
{
  vec3 pos = center + position * scale;
  vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0) ;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition;
}
`;

const fs = `
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
`;

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, 1, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const uniforms = {
  scale: { value: 1 },
};

var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms:       uniforms,
  vertexShader:   vs,
  fragmentShader: fs,
});

// Just need one circle and 1 center point per circle

const geometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();
const numCircles = 20;
const numEdgePointsPerCircle = 36;
const numPointsPerCircle = numEdgePointsPerCircle * 3;
const centers = new Float32Array(numCircles * 3);
const positions = new Float32Array(numPointsPerCircle * 3);

const radius = 10;
let off = 0;

for (let c = 0; c < numCircles; ++c) {
  const cx = rand(-100, 100);
  const cy = rand(-100, 100);
  centers[c * 2 + 0] = cx;
  centers[c * 2 + 1] = cy;
}

for (let p = 0; p < numEdgePointsPerCircle; ++p) {
  const a0 = (p + 0) * Math.PI * 2 / numEdgePointsPerCircle;
  const a1 = (p + 1) * Math.PI * 2 / numEdgePointsPerCircle;
  positions[off + 0] = 0;        
  positions[off + 1] = 0;        
  positions[off + 2] = 0;
  positions[off + 3] = Math.cos(a0);        
  positions[off + 4] = Math.sin(a0);        
  positions[off + 5] = 0;
  positions[off + 6] = Math.cos(a1);        
  positions[off + 7] = Math.sin(a1);        
  positions[off + 8] = 0;
  off += 9;
}
 
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
geometry.addAttribute('center', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(centers, 3));

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, shaderMaterial );

scene.add(mesh);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: document.querySelector("canvas"),
});

function rand(min, max) {
  return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
}

function resize(renderer, camera, force) {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (force || canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);  // pass false so three doesn't mess up the css
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds
  
  resize(renderer, camera);
  
  uniforms.scale.value = 10 + Math.sin(time) * 5;
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
resize(renderer, camera, true);
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/86/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working.  They're now just scaling nearly imperceptibly.  Checked out your edited post suggesting keeping a ref to the centers of the circles.  Do you think I should give that a go?

Comment: Unless your normals are bad just adding the normals should work. Increase your scale. What size are your circles? Normals are usually unit vectors so a scale of 1 will add 1 unit. If your circles are 1 unit large then they'll double in size. If your circles are 100 units large they'll only grow to 101 if the scale is 1. Using the other solution is just the same as setting all the positions for a particular circle to the center point, the shader would stay the same. If you keep the normals you'll basically get the same result.

Comment: Just to make it more confusing though you could use instancing so you don't have to repeat the center point of each point of each circle.